# Make reactive value handle NULL on start

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

When `input$some_selection` changes after initiation, only the first observer gets invalidated. This seems to be because on initiation, the reactive value `input_some_selection` is set to `NULL` and not updated anymore.

When pressing the radio buttons, output looks like this:

```
[1] "observed at point 1"
[1] "observed at point 2" # as expected until here
[1] "observed at point 1"
# why not invalidate the second observer also?
[1] "observed at point 1" 
[1] "observed at point 1"
[1] "observed at point 1"
```

1) Why this behavior? Is it due to the initial `NULL` value?

2) What can I do to make the example work (make the second observer invalidate when `input$some_selection` changes, i.e. generate dependency)?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      radioButtons(inputId = "some_selection", 
                   "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  eventlog<-c("")

  input_some_selection <- reactive({
    input$some_selection
  })

  observeEvent(input$some_selection, {
    print("observed at point 1")
    eventlog<<-c(eventlog,"observed at point 1")
  } )

  observeEvent(input_some_selection, {
    print("observed at point 2")
    eventlog<<-c(eventlog,"observed at point 2")
  } )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little typo. Reactive values must of course be accessed by a function call:

```
observeEvent(input_some_selection(), {
    print("observed at point 2")
    eventlog<<-c(eventlog,"observed at point 2")
  } )
```

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactive.html

Output now as expected:

```
[1] "observed at point 1"
[1] "observed at point 2"
[1] "observed at point 1"
[1] "observed at point 2"
# ...
```

Comment: It is always good to check for null. in the observe event you can say 
  `if (is.null(input$some_selection)) return(NULL)`  You can also render" please make a selection on the UI` if null is selected